# How is checkoutProvider implemented?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, data-provider

How is the Onepage checkoutProvider implemented and how could a custom provider be written for a similar component, for example a product page "productProvider" specific to that product, with all of the frontend for the page written in uiComponents?

Comment: Would like to know the same, did you make any progress in finding out?

Comment: With great difficulty, it wasn't documented at the time but you can trace it through the source code, it's echoed out into the base of onepage checkout somewhere, if that helps.